# Calculate MD5 of a string in C++

Tags: c++, linux, string, hash, md5

I have a nice example of memory mapped files that calculates the MD5 hash of a file. That works fine with no problems.

I would like to change it to calculate the MD5 hash of a string.

So the example is:

(include `#include <openssl/md5.h>` to run this code, and also boost stuff if you want to run the one with the file)

```
unsigned char result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source src(path);
MD5((unsigned char*)src.data(), src.size(), result);

std::ostringstream sout;
sout<<std::hex<<std::setfill('0');
for(long long c: result)
{
    sout<<std::setw(2)<<(long long)c;
}
return sout.str();
```

The change I made is:

```
std::string str("Hello");
unsigned char result[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
MD5((unsigned char*)str.c_str(), str.size(), result);

std::ostringstream sout;
sout<<std::hex<<std::setfill('0');
for(long long c: result)
{
    sout<<std::setw(2)<<(long long)c;
}
return sout.str();
```

But this produces the result:

```
8b1a9953c4611296a827abf8c47804d7
```

While the command `$ md5sum <<< Hello` gives the result:

```
09f7e02f1290be211da707a266f153b3
```

Why don't the results agree? Which one is wrong?

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

So I got the right answer which is ticked down there. The correct way to call `md5sum` from terminal is:

```
$ printf '%s' "Hello" | md5sum
```

To avoid the new line being included.

Comment: Is there a carriage return in the file?

Comment: @Slava There's no file. The "Hello" is merely a string. Could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: 8b1a9953c4611296a827abf8c47804d7 is correct for the string Hello

Comment: sorry missed part where you pass the string as standard input. Why don't you print src.data() and src.size() and compare?

Comment: where did you get the include file?

Comment: @Passe it's part of OpenSSL. On Debian/Ubuntu, simply install libssl package, but on Windows, you need to install it or compile it yourself.

Comment: I need to use it in an embedded environement... Is there an ARM compatible version too?

Comment: @Passe You have to compile OpenSSL yourself then. There's a precompiled version probably for Raspberry Pi in Raspbian, which uses Arm Cortex 7 processor.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist thanks for your support. I have found a fully c compliant version with just one header and one c file. It works like a charm!

Comment: $ echo -n Hello | md5sum

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are passing a final newline to the `md5sum` program, but not to your code.

You can see that the bash `<<<` operator adds a newline:

```
$ od -ta <<<Hello
0000000   H   e   l   l   o  nl
0000006
```

To avoid this, use `printf`:

```
$ printf '%s' Hello | od -ta
0000000   H   e   l   l   o
0000005
$ printf '%s' Hello | md5sum
8b1a9953c4611296a827abf8c47804d7  -
```

---

Alternatively, you could include a newline in your program version:

```
std::string str("Hello\n");
```